# Visualize Batch-Transform-Model-Quality-On-schedule Result Metrics

Tags: model, monitoring, amazon-sagemaker, drift, amazon-sagemaker-studio

How can i visualize batch transform Model Quality Monitoring violation reports only sagemaker studio ??

I try to do Model Quality Monitoring using Batch Transform job notebook in AWS

Answer (score 1):

Currently, there isn't visualization capabilities enabled for Batch Transform Model Monitoring jobs in Studio and are limited to SageMaker Endpoints, however you could leverage the API to list the executions [Reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/APIReference/API_ListMonitoringExecutions.html)